# Can't solve the "Gradle Sync fails"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am new to Android Studio development, and I encountered a problem when creating my new Android project.
Synchronization with Gradle fails:

> Gradle sync failed: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip'

I have searched (I believe) everywhere, without finding a solution that works for me. I've tried to "Sync Project with Gradle files", change the version of Gradle being used, install and use gradle locally, delete the "~ / .gradle / wrapper / dists" folder ... nothing does not work, but I do not despair.
Here are some of the last lines of the "idea.log", hoping that can help you:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.logging.Logger
> at org.gradle.api.logging.Logging.getLogger(Logging.java:38)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry.(PersistentDaemonRegistry.java:50)
> ... 65 more
> 2020-12-05 22:19:51,778 [  14945]   WARN - ues.SyncIssueUsageReporterImpl - Multiple sync failures reported. Discarding: SDK_BUILD_TOOLS_TOO_LOW
> 2020-12-05 22:19:51,787 [  14954]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home
> 2020-12-05 22:19:51,793 [  14960]   INFO - dle.roots.GradleBuildRootIndex - /Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/TopQuiz: org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.scripting.gradle.roots.New@af8c711 -> org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.scripting.gradle.roots.Imported@edd44f4
> 2020-12-05 22:19:51,794 [  14961]   INFO - System.util.ExternalSystemUtil - External project [/Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/TopQuiz] resolution task executed in 2009 ms.
> 2020-12-05 22:19:51,798 [  14965]   WARN - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip'.

I am under MacOS Big Sur 11.0.1, with Android Studio 4.1.1.
Thanks for your help !

EDIT : I've tried to build from the cli (so with my local distrib) on my project root by using

```
gradle build
```

and I've got the same error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.logging.Logger
...
* Exception is:
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.logging.Logger
    at org.gradle.api.logging.Logging.getLogger(Logging.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction.<init>(DebugLoggerWarningAction.java:57)
...
```

Any help ?

Thank's.

Comment: i think you opened a ready project named topquiz.right?

Comment: Hi Amir, thank's for looking at my problem. Yes you're right, I also tried to open other projects, but the sync stil fails.

Comment: are you living in iran or countries that google restricted services for them? i guess it from your profile name.

Comment: Not at all... I don't think that's the issue.